# Find distance in Google maps angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**I want to implement google map in angular application.**

I am new to the google map api implementation.

In google map (https://www.google.co.in/maps/@12.9475249,80.1236216,16z?hl=en) using right click option with measure distance property, I can draw an area in the google map.

After I drew I can see the total area and the distance.

But in Google api, I don't know how to implement this.

Finally I found an option like drawing tools,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Here I can draw area using free type or polygon or something.

Is this method used to do this option?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following plugin to populate google map.
https://ngmap.github.io/

Use drawing manager, to draw in the map.

Use the directive on-overlaycomplete to know when the user is complete the drawing. After complete we can use google's compute area

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(e.overlay.getPath()))
```

Sample example
http://plnkr.co/edit/N977xY55k7OCC3HOg7bM?p=preview